# SharePoint App : Lookup field always empty?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I've been struggling for the last couple days to fix this issue with no success.

I have a list with this content type and columns :

[image: DurationSettings list]

When i go to my list containing the lookup field , which reads from the Hours column the lookup field is empty :

[image: Leave request list]

Here is my Elements.xml for the lookup field StartDateDuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
<Field
   ID="{edc54aac-a1ab-474a-b0d5-cb0fb0865b4a}"
   Name="StartDateDuration"
   StaticName="StartDateDuration"
   DisplayName="Start Date Duration"
   Type="Lookup"
   List="Lists/DurationSettings"
   Required="TRUE"
   ShowField="Hours"
   Group="Leave Request App Group">
   </Field>
  </Elements>
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Its a strange issue.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to give priority to the feature which deploys the list that you want to lookup for (the source list). You can do that by changing the feature activation order in the Package manifest.